# Visualize C++ 2d array by output an image

Tags: c++, arrays, image, bmp

I have an 2d array and I want to scale and visualize it by generate an image from it. I tried the EasyBMP library and wrote the following code

```
#include "EasyBMP.h"
void visulize2DArray(double **data, int dim1, int dim2, const char* filename)           {
        double min = data[0][0];
        double max = data[0][0];
        for( int i=0 ; i < dim1; i++ )
        {
            for( int j=0; j < dim2 ; j++ )
            {
                if( data[i][j] < min )
                    { min = data[i][j]; }
                if( data[i][j] > max )
                    { max = data[i][j]; }
            }
        }
        BMP Output;
        Output.SetSize(dim1,dim2);
        Output.SetBitDepth(8);
        // plot the pixels
        for( int i=0 ; i < dim1 ; i++ )
        {   
            for( int j=0; j < dim2 ; j++ )
            {
                double scaled_value = ( data[i][j] - min )/( max-min + 1e-16 );
                int pixel_value = (int) floor(scaled_value * 255.0);
                BYTE val = (BYTE) pixel_value;
                Output(i,j)->Red = val; 
                Output(i,j)->Green = val;
                Output(i,j)->Blue = val;
                Output(i,j)->Alpha = 0;
            }
        }
        // save the file
        Output.WriteToFile( filename );
}
```

I use the above function to generate a image, however, the generated BMP file is very big: over 200M (about 10,000 * 10,000 image size), and it cannot open. I want to look into whether it is the problem of image size, so I tried to test with  a small 2d array:

```
double **testImg;
testImg = new double*[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    testImg[i] = new double[100];
for (int i=0; i<100; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<100; ++j)
    {
        testImg[i][j]=j;
    }
visulize2DArray(testImg, 100, 100, "Ctest.bmp");
```

However, the generated bmp file still cannot open. I use EasyBMP 1.0 version, as it is easy to use: I just need to include the head file, no compiling and so on.

My question is: are there any other simple way to visualize 2d array by image in C++? I know I can export the value and save to file and then using other tools. But I need to visualize it in C++.

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944787/making-a-png-or-other-image-from-array-of-pixels-in-c

Comment: Link is broken. @tonysdg

Comment: @JohannBurgess: Not sure where that question went, but this is the best I can do: https://web.archive.org/web/20120416142937/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944787/making-a-png-or-other-image-from-array-of-pixels-in-c

Comment: thank you! @tonysdg